# C++ -- How could I create a list that contains functions, and would either run the top or iterate through and run all?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

I'm not sure how to phrase this to be perfectly accurate to my goal implementation

I need a dynamic scene/menu system. I'm going to create a base class and inherit in two other classes specific to either rendering a scene or controlling a menu chain. From here I'll be creating functions with specific draw characteristics (such as a specific menu) and run them into my draw function.

What type of container system would work? I need it to be able to both run only the top and run all of the ones loaded in it (I specify because you cant iterate through a stack, from what I'm told)

Comment: This sounds like a stackoverflow question, not SE gamedev

Comment: I was gonna post it there, too, actually

Comment: Cross-posting is a no-no. :)

Comment: I didn't know that, I apologize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the STL, you can create a `vector` of function pointers.

To do that, as I guess you want to do something like `object->function()` you need all this functions to have the same prototype (parameters type and return type).

Then, you declare a function pointer type like this

```
<return_type> (<class_name>::*<type_name>)(<parameter_list>);
```

So, for example:

```
typedef void (MenuItem::*drawFuncType)();
```

Then, you just `#include <vector>` and then declare a vector like

```
std::vector<drawFuncType> funcVector;
```

And you fill it using `&draw1` for vector's insertion function.

If you had to do it for multiple classes, you can achieve this using templates for the class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's literally exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much!

Comment: Using `std::function` over function-pointers might be a nicer alternative.

Comment: how does one use `std::function`?

Also, I cant get this to work. The vector wont take that as input;

Comment: What's exactly the error you get?

Comment: Please note that there was a `typedef` missing. Anyway, please provide a description of the errors you're getting.

Comment: There are docs available about `std::function` and `std::bind`, but the general idea is to use a type like `std::function<returnType(param1type, param2type)>`. You then use `std::bind` to generate `std::function` objects that "point" to member methods of specific objects.